# How to create a multi-dimensional array from an indexed array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

- I have a 2D array that its first dimension is an index array and the second one is an associative array.
- In the array, there are some duplicates fields that I want to merge them, and for the other unduplicated fields, I want to make a third dimension array and push them there.

---

### This is my code and array:

The entire code works correctly just the "datacontractor" field that is my third dimension does not work well.

```
        <?php
    $array=Array
    (
        "0" => Array
        (
                "sid" => 10,
                "contractorid" => 1,
                "fname" => "hi",
                "lname" => "fam",
                "sname" => "saba",
                "materialname" => "beton",
                "netweight" => 100,
            ),
        "1" => Array
        (
                "sid" => 16,
                "contractorid" => 2,
                "fname" => "a",
                "lname" => "a",
                "sname" => "khoram",
                "materialname" => "kk",
                "netweight" => 200,
            ),
        "2" => Array
        (
                "sid" => 16,
                "contractorid" => 7,
                "fname" => "a",
                "lname" => "a",
                "sname" => "khoram",
                "materialname" => "kk",
                "netweight" => 777,
            ),
        "3" => Array
        (
            "sid" => 10,
            "contractorid" => 5,
            "fname" => "hi",
            "lname" => "fam",
            "sname" => "saba",
            "materialname" => "beton",
            "netweight" => 200,
        ),
        "4" => Array
        (
            "sid" => 10,
            "contractorid" => 8,
            "fname" => "hi",
            "lname" => "fam",
            "sname" => "saba",
            "materialname" => "beton",
            "netweight" => 600,
        ),
        "5" => Array
        (
            "sid" => 15,
            "contractorid" => 9,
            "fname" => "hi",
            "lname" => "fam",
            "sname" => "saba",
            "materialname" => "beton",
            "netweight" => 400,
        ),

    );

    $finalarray[]= array();
    $sidlist= array();
    $arraycount=count($array);
    for($i=0;$i<$arraycount ;$i++) {
        array_push($sidlist,$array[$i]["sid"]);
    }
    $sidlist = array_unique($sidlist);
    $sidlistcount=count($sidlist);
    $sidlist1=array();
    foreach ($sidlist as $m){
        array_push($sidlist1,$m);
    }


    for ($i = 0;$i<$sidlistcount ; $i++){
        $id=$sidlist1[$i];
        $datacontractor[$id]= array();
        for ($j = 0;$j<$arraycount ; $j++){
            if ($id==$array[$j]["sid"]){
                $contractorid = $array[$j]["contractorid"];
                $netweight = $array[$j]["netweight"];
                $finalarray[$i]=array(
                    "sid" => $id,
                    "fname" => $array[$j]["fname"],
                    "lname" => $array[$j]["lname"],
                    "sname" => $array[$j]["sname"],
                    "materialname" => $array[$j]["materialname"],
                    "datacontractor" => $datacontractor[$id],

                );


                $datacontractor[$id]["$contractorid"]=$netweight;
                echo $id,"<br>";
            }

        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($finalarray);
    echo '<pre>';
```

---

---

### This is my output of this code:

### but it has wrong answer in "datacontractor" field.

```
Array ([0] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 10
        [fname] => hi
        [lname] => fam
        [sname] => saba
        [materialname] => beton
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (
                [1] => 100
                [5] => 200

            )

    )[1] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 16
        [fname] => a
        [lname] => a
        [sname] => khoram
        [materialname] => kk
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (
                [2] => 200


            )

    )[2] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 15
        [fname] => hi
        [lname] => fam
        [sname] => saba
        [materialname] => beton
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (

            )

    ))
```

### And Finally My desired output is:

Please check and tell me what my fault is.

```
Array ([0] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 10
        [fname] => hi
        [lname] => fam
        [sname] => saba
        [materialname] => beton
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (
                [1] => 100
                [5] => 200
                [8] => 600 
            )

    )[1] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 16
        [fname] => a
        [lname] => a
        [sname] => khoram
        [materialname] => kk
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (
                [2] => 200
                [7] => 777

            )

    )[2] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 15
        [fname] => hi
        [lname] => fam
        [sname] => saba
        [materialname] => beton
        [datacontractor] => Array
            (

                [9] => 400
            )

    ))
```

---

Comment: Does this come from a database query?

Comment: not now but coming later

Comment: It is much better to do this task in SQL rather than PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `"datacontractor" => $datacontractor[$id]` to `finalarray` before finish insert all the data to the `$datacontractor[$id]` -> do that in separate loop.

You code is much more complicated then you actually need.

Consider the following short version:

```
$array = []; // this is just some of the fields - you can add all of then here 
$array[] = array("id"=> 10, "contractorid" => 1,"netweight" => 100);
$array[] = array("id"=> 16, "contractorid" => 2,"netweight" => 200);
$array[] = array("id"=> 16, "contractorid" => 7,"netweight" => 777);
$array[] = array("id"=> 10, "contractorid" => 5,"netweight" => 200);
$array[] = array("id"=> 10, "contractorid" => 8,"netweight" => 600);
$array[] = array("id"=> 15, "contractorid" => 9,"netweight" => 400);

$ans = [];
foreach($array as $e) {
    if (!isset($ans[$e['id']])) { // if never set do first time
        $ans[$e['id']] = array("sid" => $e['id'], "datacontractor" => array($e["contractorid"] => $e["netweight"])); // here you can add all your other fields as fname, lname...
    } else {
        $ans[$e['id']]["datacontractor"][$e["contractorid"]] = $e["netweight"]; // just add the new field as already set
    }
}
```

Now, `$ans` will output your desire

**Edit**:

For having multi `contractorid` value change to this:

```
foreach($array as $e) {
    if (!isset($ans[$e['id']])) { // if never set do first time
        $ans[$e['id']] = array("sid" => $e['id'], "datacontractor" => array($e["contractorid"] => [$e["netweight"]])); // notice "contractorid" has array inside (extra "[]" around $e["netweight"])
    } else {
        $ans[$e['id']]["datacontractor"][$e["contractorid"]][] = $e["netweight"]; // append to the contractorid array
    }
}
```

For re-index `$ans` do this at the end: `$ans = array_values($ans);`

Comment: hi i found a problem in the code...for a specific `sid` if we have a same `contractorid` and different `netweight`, in the out put we only have the last one and it will become override...

Comment: for example:`"1" => Array
        (
                "sid" => 16,
                "contractorid" => 2,
                "materialname" => "kk",
                "netweight" => 200,
            ),
        "2" => Array
        (
                "sid" => 16,
                "contractorid" => 2,
                "materialname" => "kk",
                "netweight" => 777,
            ),`  in output in `datacontractor` we only have `2=>777` but we should have `2=>200` and `2=>777`

Comment: That right - because associative array force unique of keys - if you want to have different `netweight` for the same `contractorid` then the `contractorid` field should be another array with all the `netweight`s (is this what you need?)

Comment: yes it is , so what shoud i do?... and some other problem there is too.... when print the`$ans` array indexes of second array are same with `id`s  ,though it should start with 0 and increase automatically like normal indexes array..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_reduce**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$data = array_reduce($array, function ($old, $new) {
    if (isset($old[$new['sid']])) {
        $new['datacontractor'] = array_merge($old[$new['sid']]['datacontractor'], [$new['netweight']]);
        $old[$new['sid']] = $new;
    } else {
        $new['datacontractor'] = [$new['netweight']];
    }
    unset($new['netweight']);
    $old[$new['sid']] = $new;
    return $old;
}, []);

$data = array_values($data);
print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
print '</pre>';
```